# PIVOT/UNPIVOT multiple rows and columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with the following (very simplified) data:

```
ID   Value1   Value2   Value3
-----------------------------
1    5        7        Test
2    4        7        Test2
```

I want to get each column name and the value in the row for that column; so, my desired output would look like this:

```
Column        1        2
----------------------------
Value1        5        4
Value2        7        7
Value3        Test     Test2
```

I've been playing with PIVOT and UNPIVOT but can't quite figure it out.  Any help would be appreciated.

[SQLFiddle here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f4b23/1).

Comment: how many value columns do you have in all?

Comment: @vkp:  Assume the three listed.  Once I have a simple example working, I can expand it using dynamic sql for an arbitrary number of columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, what comes to mind is a `union all` with conditional aggregation:

```
select 'Value1',
       max(case when id = 1 then value1 end) as [1],
       max(case when id = 2 then value1 end) as [2]
from t
union all
select 'Value2',
       max(case when id = 1 then value2 end) as [1],
       max(case when id = 2 then value2 end) as [2]
from t
select 'Value3',
       max(case when id = 1 then value3 end) as [1],
       max(case when id = 2 then value3 end) as [2]
from t;
```

I think you can do it with `pivot`/`unpivot`, but I think this is simpler.

Comment: i was thinking the same..but assumed the `id` column could potentially have many values, in which case, this would be a bit cumbersome

Comment: Thank you!  This is what I need.